# Out of memory Exception . c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8))
using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
 {
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    ServiceModel toReturn = serializer.Deserialize<ServiceModel>(reader);
    String resps = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toReturn, Formatting.Indented);
  }
```

Getting OutOfMemory exception on after this line :

`String resps = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toReturn, Formatting.Indented);` .

How to Handle this in C#(Compact Framework).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is some circular reference... use http://www.ndepend.com/Features/#DependencyCycle to check this